# How to search all matching previous commands using ctrl+R in Linux

Tags: linux, unix, search, root

I was looking for the method of listing all the previous commands matching to a particular input. e.g. I am in the following working directory

```
[root@kayan /home]#
```

Now I am looking for a previous command e.g.

```
less /home/kayan/scripts/ave.sh
```

So when I pressed ctrl+R and typed ave.sh, it is only showing my last used command i.e.

```
(reverse-i-search)`ave.sh': vi ave.sh
```

I need the method to see all the previous commands that matches with ave.sh

Comment: If you type ctrl+R again you will be able to display older previous commands that match your search (it doesn't provide a list though).

Comment: Thanks @CélineAussourd ... You are right... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you press Ctrl+R and type your search, you will get the last record matching this search.

If you press Ctrl+R again you will get the previous record. You can press Ctlr+R repetitively to get older matches.

This doesn't provide a list though.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you can do this using Ctrl+R, but you can leverage `history` command and achieve similar result:

```
man history:

NAME
       history - GNU History Library
```

Add a function to your `~/.bashrc` that checks a history.

For example:

```
h() { history | grep "$1" | grep "$2" | grep "$3" | head -10 | sed 's/[^ ]*  //'; }
```

Then you would need to copy and paste the result.  ( You may also need to adjust `sed` command to strip out number and spaces more accuratly)